# system hangs at reboot/shutdown

Tags: shutdown, reboot

after performing a clean install of Lubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, 64 bit, I experience shutdown/reboot problems. The system hangs at a specific point.

After deactivating plymouth ("noplymouth" instead of "quiet splash") I was able to find out where the system hangs.
The last entries are as follows:

```
systemd-shutdow [1]: 12 output lines suppressed due to rate limiting
systemd-shutdown [1]: Syncing filesytems and block devices
systemd-shutdown [1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes
systemd-journald [284]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdown)
systemd-shutdown [1]: Sendig SIKILL to remaining processes ...
systemd-shutdown [1]: Unmountig file systems
EXT4-fs (sdc1): re-mounted. Opts: block_validity,barrier,user-xattr,acl,errors=remount-ro
systemd-shutdown [1]: All filesystems unmounted
systemd-shutdown [1]: Deactivating swaps
systemd-shutdown [1]: All swaps deactivated
systemd-shutdown [1]: Deactivating loop devices
systemd-shutdown [1]: All loop devices detached
systemd-shutdown [1]: Detaching DM devices
kvm: exiting hardware virtualization
```

So the kvm thing seems to be the culprit.

Does anyone know what to do?

The whole thing is a bit odd as I have a pristine system and everything should work perfectly.

Comment: Check logs with explanations: `journalctl -xe`, or just logs starting form priority=warning and above: `journalctl -b 0 -p warning`, or what services failed: `systemctl --failed` and then those specific services with `systemctl status servicename.service`.

Comment: Tnx. systemctl --state=failed gives me: 
`● postfix@-a.service loded failed failed Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)
● xpra.service      loaded failed failed Xpra System Server `.Nothing seems to hint to kvm.

Comment: What about all the others ways to read logs? Also you could extend your question providing more info: `inxi -SCG && systemd-analyze time && systemd-analyze blame | head`. Seems [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dellserver/+bug/1777674/)

Comment: Tnx for the link. I´ll have to dig deeper. For the time being this command seems to work from the terminal:`shutdown -H -P +0`.